# Angular router event NavigationEnd not firing when expected

Tags: angular

I have an alert in html with a * ngIf = "alertValue",and in ts I have a function with an 'if' and I wish I could activate my alert when the value goes to "true"

I tried

html

```
<div *ngIf="alertValue">
       <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
          A simple primary alert—check it out!
       </div>
     </div>
```

Ts

```
alertValue= false;
 this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.showNotif(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state);
    }
 });

showNotif(data: any) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data !== undefined) {
    this.alertValue= true;
    console.warn(this.alertValue);
  }
}
```

in the `"console.log (data);"` I recover well my value "hello",
and in `"console.warn (this.alertValue);"` I recover "true" which is good.

But my alert is not activated in the html.
I tried to put a button that allows to pass "true" to my "alertValue" and my alert activates

so I understand how to activate my alert during the function

If you have an idea, I'm interested

Comment: You are setting `showNotifValide` in your typescript file and your HTML file is using alertValue... You should use the same property...
I think we are missing some informations about your problem, could you provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: where subscribe to this.router.events? I think that you must put in your ngOnInit function

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to call `router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state` earlier. Since it's too late it's not triggering changes.

The navigation has already ended in `ngOnInit`.  Try putting it in the constructor instead.

```
// earliest life cycle 
constructor() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            // subscribing to NavigationEnd which is about to happen
        }
    });
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            // subscribing to NavigationEnd which already ended so it's waiting
        }
    });
}
```

Let me know if you need more help but also explain more about your code and I will watch this question.

Comment: hello, yes I understand what you tell me, the "this.showNotif (this.router.getCurrentNavigation (). extras.state);" and and in the NgOnInit (),

Comment: you advise me to put it or? Thank you for your help