# An Angular website is broken after it's published in GitHub Pages but works on local

Tags: angular, github, github-pages, angular-routing, angular-router

Recently, I upgraded my app from Angular 9 to 12 (one by one, I didn't jump straight away) and it looks perfect when I lunch it on my local PC:

[image: preview 1]

But when I published and uploaded it to GitHub Pages is broken completely *(there is nothing in the console)*:

[image: preview 2]

I'm almost convinced the issue is related to the **`osm-map.component.ts`** component which is unrelated to the migration. I expanded this component to collect more options via `GET`:

```
constructor(private service: OsmMessageServiceService, private translateService: TranslateService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
        .subscribe(e => {
        if (e.constructor.name === 'NavigationEnd' && this.router.navigated) {
            this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {

            let isDraggable = true;
            let isMetric = true;

            if (params['isApp']) {
                this.status = params['isApp'] == "true" ? true : false;
            }
            if (params['isMetric']) {
                isMetric = params['isMetric'] == "true" ? true : false;
                if (!isMetric) {
                this.defaultUnits = 'ft/s²';
                }
            }
            if (params['newLoc']) {
                this.newLoc = params['newLoc'].split(',').map(Number);
            }

            localStorage.setItem('isMetric', `${isMetric}`);
            localStorage.setItem('defaultUnits', this.defaultUnits);

            this.resizeMap();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I even published these changes with the V9 and the bug kept happening in GitHub Pages.

The rest of the changes are minimal since I did minor changes in the help because of some API changes in the **`ng-bootstrap`** tabs but they are invisible.

This is how I publish my website:

> ng build --prod --base-href
> "https://fanmixco.github.io/gravitynow-angular/"

This is a temporal website with the broken case:

https://fanmixco.github.io/gnow-temp/

Some cases:

- https://fanmixco.github.io/gnow-temp?isApp=true
- https://fanmixco.github.io/gnow-temp/?isApp=true&isMetric=false

The worst part is that I don't get any error or warning in the JS console that could give me an idea about the root cause.

[image: preview 3]

I noticed that the `NavigationEnd` never happens because I added some logs:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit");
    this.router.events
      .subscribe(e => {
        console.log("event subscriber started");
        if (e.constructor.name === 'NavigationEnd' && this.router.navigated) {
          console.log("NavigationEnd");
```

[image: console]

Also, if I run the compiled version on my PC, it works fine also (I must remove the GitHub URL in the `index.html` before). Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**P.S.:**

This is my repo if you want to check it:

https://github.com/FANMixco/gravitynow-angular

Comment: You mention you expanded the component to get data via a `GET`. Do you recieve any error codes on any requests it makes?

Comment: Have you rolled back the version on github pages publication? Because it looks good when i check. Could it been a hick-up with the map api?

Comment: Hi @Tommi, yes, I rolled it back because it's part of another app. Let me create a fake repo.

Comment: @Tommi, a temporal fake site is this one: https://fanmixco.github.io/gnow-temp/

Comment: @theKunz, I get no errors.

Comment: Can you try and load up incrementally each version from 9 to 12 to github? So start with loading up 10 and see if the behaviour is still the same if not keep going to 11 and then 12

Comment: Hi @Tommi, I had tried that before. I am almost convinced that the issue is in the GET part because once I kept the V9 and the GET part and the bug persisted.

Comment: Also @Tommi, I did the incremental step by step, I was unsure the migration from 9 to 12 would be successful.

Comment: My bad, didnt read that the bug persisted after reverting back to V9. I thought it could've been a change to the httpclient in one of the versions after 9 that could be the culprit.

Comment: Hi @Tommi, I noticed that the `NavigationEnd` never happens because I added some logs. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56634968/1928691

I had to move the function from the `ngOnInit()` to the `constructor` and to do some minor tweaks like adding a different if `if (event instanceof NavigationEnd)`. This is the final code:

```
constructor(private service: OsmMessageServiceService, private translateService: TranslateService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { 
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
```

After this is done, then, the app starts working as expected.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Sorry i couldnt be of more help. But just for curiosity, you had the app published and working with Angular v9. And then upgraded it to v12 (step by step) and when publishing again it stopped working? And when reverting back to v9 it still didnt work?

Comment: Hi @Tommi, yes, the main issue was related to the new features I added to the query strings. I added the `NavigationEnd` because the subscribe was triggered too many times and the resize or the data was very randomly loaded. Oddly, when I launched on my PC all was working fine but it never worked in GitHub Pages (I'm not sure about other hosting). My advice is to move it to the constructor of the GET collection and add the if that I added :).